# Don't hide the link to the duplicate target so well

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions

This is a screenshot of one of my old posts here on MSE that was closed as a duplicate. The height of the visible area is exactly what is visible in a maximized browser on my current screen. I'm seeing that the question is closed as a duplicate, but where exactly can I find this duplicate?

[image]

Well, as most people here on MSE know you can't actually find the link to the duplicate on this screenshot. That's because it's actually at the top of the question, which isn't visible anymore because I scrolled down.

Duplicates are probably one of the most important features of the entire Q&A system. We want people to find them because the best answer is probably in the linked duplicate, and not on the closed question. **Why do we hide the duplicate link so well if they're that important?**

The duplicate link should be far more visible. It should be present at the top of the question **and** below the close banner. It shouldn't be just a link, it should be a excerpt of the question like we show in question lists. It should be big and impossible to overlook, just short of making it a blinking marquee tag.

Comment: I support this. It's not unusual to get comments asking where they can find the link for the duplciate if their question was closed. I am not sure if they also need to refresh the page to see the banner.